# Поиск по связанному полю моделей в Django 1.6.5

Tags: python, django

Поддерживаю существующий проект, который был сделан на Django 1.6.5. 
Есть две связанные модели: [image]
Код моделей следующий:

```
class SomeServer(model.Model):
    idn = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, null=True, blank=True, unique=True,
        validators=[domain_validator],
        verbose_name=_("Some domain name"))
    type_id = models.IntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True, choices=server_type,
        verbose_name=_("Type of server"))
    ip = fields.IPAddressField(
        null=True, blank=True, unique=True,
        validators=[ipv4_validator], verbose_name=_("IP-address"))
    codename = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, unique=True,
        validators=[RegexValidator(r"^[0-9a-z]+$")], verbose_name=_("Code name"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("test server")
        verbose_name_plural = ugettext_noop("test servers")
        ordering = ["id"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.codename
```

Модель с зависимым полем:

```
class SomeResult(model.Model):
    testserver = models.ForeignKey(SomeServer, related_name='test_results', verbose_name=_("Test server"))
    moment = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name=_("Log file processing moment"))
```

Есть формочка для поиска:

```
class SomeResultFilterForm(forms.Form):
    testserver = forms.CharField(
        label = _(u"Test server name"),
        required = False,
    )
```

Как правильно во view задать поиск по полю testserver модели SomeResult, чтобы выводился результат из модели SomeServer поля codename. Если по данному полю в данный момент сделать поиск, то получаю ошибку:

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

Comment: Покажите как пытаетесь сделать поиск.

Comment: [Код, реализующий поиск](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/8ac67111-2074-4840-be13-4e6a7b663f87/?i=true)

Comment: Код, реализующий поиск, как раз весь спрятался в `FilteredListMixin`. Это миксин из какой-то библиотеки или самописанный?

Comment: [Код из FilteredListMixin, который реализует запрос queryset](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/61e3b805-4ba5-4825-a704-61cd410caa12/?i=true)